# Where are the source files? After git clone

Tags: git, repository

Where on earth are the files?

I cannot find the darn files after doing a git clone.

I just cloned git clone https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/

I found the hidden .git folder etc.  Tried every sensible command but I not seeing any java files ...

Yes, I know git is different but I still want real java files on my machine.

Oh and for those writing Git 101, Git Cheetsheet, Git Vs. SVN, yes getting the files from a remote repo is the first thing we need to know.  Not a lot of slick commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `git clone https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/` and look at the `libgdx` folder, you will see the only file currently in that git repository, which is `README`.

Git will not magically create Java code in an empty project.

If you look at the readme (or the project site), you'll see that it has moved to GitHub.

Comment: so how do I get the source files?

Comment: on a more important level, why not one slick command to get a copy of the source?

Comment: @AndroidPoster: Did you look at the project on Google Code? There are no source files.  There is no `git magic` command that will write code for you.  If you clone a repository that actually has source code, you will see code.

Answer (score 0):

For cloning libgdx source -
git clone https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx.git